# Port Forwarding with the real IP-address

Tags: networking, ubuntu, debian, routing, iptables

How to implement port forwarding, so that would be displayed on the host real IP and non-IP machine, as it comes with SNAT DNET with IPTABLES

The scheme is about the

**The machine-HETE with IP 1.2.3.4**

**The machine-HETE with IP 4.5.6.7**

Should that be the scheme worked as follows

**Client with IP 9.8.7.6** knocks on IP 1.2.3.4:27015> conversion??? > IP 4.5.6.7:27234 **with the client IP 9.8.7.6**

That is the rule on IPTABLES, but such a rule, I do not see the real IP addresses, please help

```
iptables-t nat-A PREROUTING-p udp - dport 27015-j DNAT - to-destination 46.174.50.44:27231 
iptables-t nat-A POSTROUTING-j MASQUERADE
```

By the way, UDP is used

Comment: what does "machine-HETE" mean? And are 1.2.3.4 and 4.5.6.7 supposed to be private IPs or public IPs?

Comment: dedicated servers 1 and 2

Comment: public ip's in internet

Comment: I think SNAT and DNAT are purely for NAT. Why do you want SNAT and DNAT at all if you want the public IP to be used?  IP Masquerading is a form of NAT. If you want the public IPs you wouldn't want NAT.

Comment: Me meed make redirect port, client 9.8.7.6 tuk tuk 27015 > DS #1 accept client amd redirect > DS #2 27015 with REAL IP client 9.8.7.6

Comment: I can't tell what you are doing here.  There are networks reserved for documentation.  Please use them instead of making up random numbers.  rfc5737 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2), and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3), or use private address space, and give us some clear descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

DNAT is most definitely what you want, yes. But what exactly is your problem? The only rule necessary is quite simple:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 27015 -j DNAT --to-destination 4.5.6.7:27015
```

...where `eth0` is the network interface to work on and `1.2.3.4` the destination to process. Of course, if your server has only one interface or only one IP address, these could be left out.

I’m too lazy to test it now, but I’m sure some problems will occur because the response packets’ return path is different.

Comment: Thanks man, but this rules not working, detection IP 1.2.3.4, not client 9.8.7.6

Comment: Come again? If you want to match die client IP instead of the redirecting server’s IP, simple use the `-s` (source) option. Naturally, these are `iptables` basics, which you can learn elsewhere.

Comment: With -s NOT WONKING

Comment: At least _try_ to write proper English. This is working perfectly. It is, however, extremely unlikely this will pass even the most basic filtering routines of a server provider, because to them this is basically IP spoofing. If you were to employ SNAT as well, this wouldn’t be an issue. The client’s IP address wouldn’t be preserved, however.

Comment: @Maya Your technical writing is perhaps not clear enough for people, so try to communicate in a way that is unambiguous and clear and can be understood without or with minimal explanation. So for example, use screenshots, use pastes from the command line / terminal. State what you expect contrast with what you get. Write in the actual public IPs but blank out one or two of the numbers.